# Define a KMDF driver as Non-isolated

Tags: windows-11, kmdf, wdf, windows-driver

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/driver-isolation, there are two types of drivers: Windows drivers and Windows Desktop drivers (Isolated and non-isolated accordingly). There is a lot of info about how to develop an isolated one, but nothing about a non-isolated one.

The driver I'm working on has to be able to use an absolute path to remove/disinfect malicious files. But if I follow restrictions for isolated drivers I can't achieve that, and obviously, the error `DRIVER_ISOLATION_VIOLATION` occurs.

The note on the MS's page explains that:

> While driver package isolation is required for Windows Drivers, Windows Desktop Drivers still benefit from it through improved resiliency and serviceability.

But there is nothing about how to define it. Does anyone know how to do that?

The Driver Validator always says that the violation occurs, even when I set **Driver Type** from *Universal* to *Desktop*

Comment: The "Windows Universal" concept has essentially petered out.  There's no point.  Just go for desktop every time.  It's a setting in the project file.